# Can URI templates be used to match URIs to routes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, uritemplate

Frameworks like ASP.NET or Nancy provide a syntax that can be used for specifying routes, such as:

```
MapRoute("/customers/{id}/invoices/{invoiceId}", ...)
```

In ASP.NET routes work in two directions. They can **match** a request URI such as  `/customers/32/invoices/19` to a route, and they can **resolve** parameters such as `{ id: 37, invoiceId: 19 }` into a URI.

[RFC 6570: URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) also defines a similar, though much richer, specification for URI's that are often used to **resolve** URI's. For example:

```
UriTemplate("/customers/{id}/invoices{/invoiceId}{?sort}", { id: 37, invoiceId: 19, sort: 'asc' } )
// returns:  /customers/37/invoices/19?sort=asc
```

My question is, can the syntax specified in RFC 6570 be used to **match** request URI's to routes? Is there a part of the syntax that would make it ambiguous to match a given URI to a given URI template? Are there any libraries that support matching a URI to a URI template?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which technology are you using? Why do you want to use RFC6570? What have you tried and what have failed for you?

Comment: Have you seen my answer below? Look at the function `ldoToRouter`. A JSON Schema Link Description Object (LDO) is your UriTemplate plus the method, e.g. {"href":"/customers/{id}/invoices{/invoiceId}{?sort}", "method": "get"} ...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it would be very difficult.  Certainly things like the prefix syntax would make it impossible to regenerate the original parameters.

For things like path segment expansion

```
 {/list*}           /red/green/blue
```

How would you know which parts of the path were literals and which parts were part of the parameter?  There are lots of fairly freaky behavior in the URITemplate spec, I suspect even if it is possible to match, it would be fairly expensive.

Are you interested in doing this for the purposes of routing?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple regarding **match** but regarding **resolve** you need to replace the ASP.net part by the RFC 6570.

Unfortunately I am doing this in node with express js and this might not be helpful, but I am sure something like https://github.com/geraintluff/uri-templates (for resolving) is also available in ASP.

Here is some .js code to illustrate the rewriting of a [hyperschema](http://json-schema.org)
USING RFC 6570 to use with express js (the advantage of the use within schema is that you could also define regexes for your uri templates):

> ```
>   var deref = require('json-schema-deref');
>   var tv4 = require('tv4');
>   var url = require('url');
>   var rql = require('rql/parser');
>   var hyperschema = {
>   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema",
>   "links": [
>     {
>       "href": "{/id}{/ooo*}{#q}",
>       "method": "GET",
>       "rel": "self",
>       "schema": {
>         "type": "object",
>         "properties": {
>           "params": {
>             "type": "object",
>             "properties": {
>               "id": {"$ref": "#/definitions/id"}
>             },
>             "additionalProperties": false
>           }
>         },
>         "additionalProperties": true
>       }
>     }
>   ],
>   "definitions": {
>     "id": {
>       "type": "string",
>       "pattern": "[a-z]{0,3}"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

```
// DOJO lang AND _
function getDottedProperty(object, parts, create) {
    var key;
    var i = 0;

    while (object && (key = parts[i++])) {
        if (typeof object !== 'object') {
            return undefined;
        }
        object = key in object ? object[key] : (create ? object[key] = {} : undefined);
    }

    return object;
}
function getProperty(object, propertyName, create) {
    return getDottedProperty(object, propertyName.split('.'), create);
}
function _rEscape(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}

function getPattern(k, ldo, customCat) {
  // ...* = explode = array
  // ...: = maxLength
  var key = ((k.slice(-1) === '*') ? k.slice(0,-1) : k).split(':')[0];
  var cat = (customCat) ? customCat : 'params'; // becomes default of customCat in TS
  var pattern = '';
  if (typeof ldo === 'object' && ldo.hasOwnProperty('schema')) {
    var res = getProperty(ldo.schema, ['properties',cat,'properties',key,'pattern'].join('.'));
    if (res) {
      console.log(['properties',cat,'properties',key,'pattern'].join('.'),res);
      return ['(',res,')'].join('');
    }
  }
  return pattern;
}
function ldoToRouter(ldo) {
  var expression = ldo.href.replace(/(\{\+)/g, '{') // encoding
    .replace(/(\{\?.*\})/g, '') // query
    .replace(/\{[#]([^}]*)\}/g, function(_, arg) {
      // crosshatch
      //console.log(arg);
      return ['(?:[/]*)?#:',arg,getPattern(arg,ldo,'anchor')].join('');
    })
    .replace(/\{([./])?([^}]*)\}/g, function(_, op, arg) {
      // path seperator
      //console.log(op, '::', arg, '::', ldo.schema);
      return [op,':',arg,getPattern(arg,ldo)].join('');
    });
    return {method: ldo.method.toLowerCase(), args:[expression]};
}

deref(hyperschema, function(err, fullSchema) {
  console.log('deref hyperschema:',JSON.stringify(fullSchema));
  var router = fullSchema.links.map(ldoToRouter);

  console.log('router:',JSON.stringify(router));
});
```